# Как в dapper передать тип значения NULL в Dictionary или dynamic

Tags: .net, dapper

У меня есть таблица с полем varbinary
если передавать в dapper свой класс с пропертей типа byte[] со заначением null - то все в порядке, а если использовать Dictionary или dynamic - то в sql параметр создается типа varchar и я получаю SqlException:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

если передать пустой массив - то все работает. но нужен NULL и нужна возможность добавить параметров динамически.

Answer (score 0):

не уверен в актуальности вопроса до сих пор, но думаю не повредит)

(SQL)varbinary -- массив элементов по 1 байт, подходит для (.Net)byte[];

> если использовать Dictionary или dynamic - то в sql параметр создается типа varchar и я получаю SqlException:
>
> > Implicit conversion from data type **nvarchar** to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

1) **n**varchar это строка переменной длины **двух**байтовых символов -- возможно просто несовпадение базового типа элементов массива/строки;

2)было б не плохо увидеть код, как именно используется Dictionary или dynamic вместо byte[] и т.д.